# Why std::string works after the initial value has been destroyed?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, scope, stdstring

A sample where std::string is corrupted cause the scope with its value ends:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

const int StackSize = 2137;

char stack[StackSize];

template <typename Type>
Type& push(Type value) {
    char *ptr = (char*)&value;
    std::copy_n(ptr, sizeof(Type), stack);
    return *(Type*)stack;
}

template <typename Type>
Type& create(Type value) {
    auto &var = push<Type>(value);
    std::cout << "Should Be: " << var << '\n';
    return var;
}

int main() {
    auto &x = create<std::string>("Hello");
    std::cout << "Is: " << x << '\n';
}
```

When I change the function push to receive a pointer the output is correct, but currently it's "b"

I understand that std::string has a pointer to a c-string and the output is different because argument of the function push is destroyed when the scope ends.

But why when I pass a pointer to push, the output is still correct? The c-string should be destroyed after create ends.

Comment: Please show the alternative code instead of describing it.

Comment: So much *undefined behaviour* in `push`...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this code ? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to store non-trivial object (std::string) in the buffer of chars via C-like `memcpy`/`copy_n`.

Obviously that fails, because you just copy it byte-by-byte there, so its data pointer points to the same location as a temporary `value` string, and then, when the data is freed by `value` destructor (at least if your compiler doesn't do SSO), you invoke UB trying to access it through your stack.

I'm not clear how the code that "works" for you looks, but I guess it just avoids the problem by allocating string on heap and not deleting it.

Consider studying how it's done in C++ (i.e. `placement new`).

Comment: I would guess it "works" due to SSO and will fail miserably for a longer string

Comment: That "working" code simply passes a pointer to push. Why is that any different? Temporary string should be destroyed after create, not push, but in main it does still work.

Comment: @Kulomb If I change `push` to accept `Type *value` then the code would just fail to compile, so I assume there are more differences besides "simply passes a pointer". I can only speculate on what they are.

Comment: The steps are: char *ptr = (char*)value and push<Type>(&value)

Comment: @Kulomb that way the std::string is created in `main` and its destructor is run at the end of `main`. So by using the pointer you avoid extra string copy and "store" only the first one which just happens to "live" until your program ends.